# ValueError: cannot infer type for <class 'NoneType'> - Flask, sqlite

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite, flask

I'm trying to upload a dataframe to sqlite database which has no problem unless I add the 'quarters' column.

```
df['quarters'] = pd.PeriodIndex(pd.df(empres_df.date), freq='Q')
df.to_sql("table_name", con, if_exists="append")
```

Because when I do, it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2446, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1951, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1949, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1935, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/Users/mkhumtai/Desktop/IndividualProject/avian/app/views.py", line 145, in import_data
    empres_df.to_sql("empres", con, if_exists="append")
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 2712, in to_sql
    method=method,
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 518, in to_sql
    method=method,
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 1747, in to_sql
    dtype=dtype,
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 1440, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 619, in __init__
    self.table = self._create_table_setup()
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 1476, in _create_table_setup
    column_names_and_types = self._get_column_names_and_types(self._sql_type_name)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 860, in _get_column_names_and_types
    for i in range(len(self.frame.columns))
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 860, in <listcomp>
    for i in range(len(self.frame.columns))
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 1532, in _sql_type_name
    col_type = lib.infer_dtype(col, skipna=True)
  File "pandas/_libs/lib.pyx", line 1246, in pandas._libs.lib.infer_dtype
ValueError: cannot infer type for <class 'NoneType'>
```

Adding the 'quarters' column to the dataframe itself doesn't give an error as long as I don't include that column to the database.

How do I fix this?

Comment: What does the problematic column contain?

Answer (score 4):

Just wanted to update,

I fixed the issue by adding

```
df['quarters'] = pd.PeriodIndex(pd.df(empres_df.date), freq='Q').astype(str)
```

As it seems that the database doesn't recognise the column type